# Add an attribute to smart category rule

Tags: magento2

Hi there is it possible to add a custom attribute to the smart category attribute list when creating a rule?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can find a setting into Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Visual Merchandiser -> Visible Attributes for Category Rules:
[image: Visual Merchandiser configurations]